# "setTimeout" VS "debounce" plugin - to defer code execution on events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, debouncing

I want to defer execution of some code on events.
What exactly is the difference between using standard `setTimeout` function and a plugin debounce ([link to debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/))?

**Here's an example with** `setTimeout`:

```
var timeout;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {

        doSomethingFunction();

    }, 500);

});
```

**And here's an example with debounce**:

```
$(window).on("scroll",

    $.debounce(500, doSomethingFunction)

);
```

Of course with debounce the code is shorter but are there any other benefits?
**Which one will be faster?**

Answer (score 12):

`debounce` uses `setTimeout` internally so the difference is related to the number of times `setTimeout` is fired.

`debounce` throttles the amount of times it fires `setTimeout`. If multiple requests are sent in a short duration, only one will come through.

```
var timeout_id = setTimeout(
    debounce_mode ? clear
    : exec, debounce_mode === undefined ? delay - elapsed
    : delay
);
```

You can review [the source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/v1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js) for more information.

The plugin will handle the timeout by setting a timeout id.